# Increasing scroll speed

Tags: xorg, mouse, mouse-scroll

I've recently switched to Ubuntu, and the one thing that has been bothering me is the scroll speed, which I can't seem to change. In windows I used to have it set around 7 lines, but it seem to be around 3 on Ubuntu, and unchangeable. How can I change the speed?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If it's only for web, you can change the scroll speed in FireFox:

- `Edit` menu > `Preferences` > `Advanced` tab > `Browsing` group: disable ***smooth scrolling***

Fine-tuning:

- Type enter `about:config` in the address bar
- Find and change `mousewheel.withnokey.sysnumlines` to FALSE
- Then change the `mousewheel.withnokey.numlines` from 1 to whatever you want.
- For Firefox versions 73.3.1 and later: - change the `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount` from 1 to whatever you want.

And a more general, system-wide solution:

- For touchpads, some drivers allow customizing scroll sensitivity, like [GPointingDeviceSettings](http://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings) (GSynaptics successor).
- For mice, [currently Gnome offers no way for a user to adjust a mouse wheel speed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtk/+bug/124440). It's a known wanted feature, triaged as WishList. A solution would be to use [some hacks](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10406312#20), or really dig deep into a mess of configuration files, and possibly some recompiles. Not fun if you need to adjust the value until you find a comfortable one.

Comment: Just unplug and plug again the mouse connector. It worked for me.

Comment: `mousewheel.withnokey` does not exist in FF v72

Comment: in FF v97 it's now `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount` and `mousewheel.system_scroll_override.enabled` but I found those didn't work (i'm on KDE).  What did work was @joeytwiddle s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/704254/27606)

Comment: My answer is from 2011, I'd be really surprised if it still worked more than 10 years later, specially in something as fast-moving as browser settings

Comment: Unplugging and replugging the little USB logitech mouse & keyboard transmitter fixed it for me.

Answer (score 29):

Just unplug the mouse (mine was wireless), and then plug it back in to fix this issue.

I was searching for a long time for this fix and even rebooted the machine to no avail.

Maybe a full shutdown would have fixed the issue.

Comment: Wow, this worked for me too with a Microsoft Wireless mouse that was scrolling far too fast. I unplugged the bluetooth dongle and re-plugged it and scrolling became perfect. Amazing that the fix was this simple.

Comment: Found the perfect solution. No more unplug and plug. Use [resetmsmice](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice/),  and [the Ubuntu package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice/files/resetmsmice_1.1.2-1_amd64.deb/download)

Answer (score 23):

For Ubuntu 12.10 I found that it it a little different for the Firefox work around.

Open `about:config` (type it into the address bar) and search for:

```
mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount
```

Then change the number associated with it. Mine was set to 5. I changed it to 60 and it works how I want it now.

Comment: Thanks! I found that option myself but didn't try that high a number, just something like 10. But together with smooth scrolling it seems that much higher numbers are in order to reach barely sufficient scroll speeds. Currently got mine set to 100.

Answer (score 5):

In Firefox 19, run `about:config` in the address bar, then modify the parameter `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount` to something higher (50). You don't have to restart FF.

Answer (score 5):

[This tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/12/how-to-change-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed.html) worked for me:

1. Open a terminal and run: `sudo apt-get install imwheel`
2. `gedit ~/.imwheelrc`
3. Paste this, save, and close gedit:

   ```
   ".*"
   None,      Up,   Button4, 3
   None,      Down, Button5, 3
   Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
   Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
   Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
   Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
   ```
4. `imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"`
5. Add the previous line to `~/.bashrc` or your session autostart manager.

Comment: While this does work - on a laptop, when I sometimes use a mouse, and sometimes the trackpad, this causes some buggy behaviour with the trackpad.

Answer (score 4):

I have Firefox 42.0 here, and I use a touchpad to scroll.

I found if I wanted to adjust the distance scrolled, I could change:

```
mousewheel.default.delta_multiplier_y
```

in `about:config`.  Its default value was `100`.  A larger value would scroll further/faster.

Answer (score 2):

Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller

In Chrome, this is The Soluttion: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb

Just brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

If you use two fingers on a **touchpad** to scroll, you can use `synclient` to adjust the sensitivity **for the whole system**.

If you don't have it installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

To see the current sensitivity threshold, check the output of:

```
synclient -l | grep ScrollDelta
```

To make it more sensitive, reduce the value:

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=33
```

This means you need to move your finger less to send each scroll event.

If you want to reverse the scroll direction, like Mac OS X's "natural scrolling", set a negative value.

But note that this **will not** let you configure the **minimum distance** scrolled when you move your fingers only a little bit.  That must be configured per-app (or possibly per-desktop environment).

Comment: only on Synaptic devices - does not apply to ALPS or indeed any other touchpad manufactuter.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the unplug/plug trick does fix the issue this is not a really good solution

One solution I found is to add

```
xinput set-prop 10 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' 10 10 10
```

at the end of my `.profile` file (or wherever it gets executed once per graphical login)

In the case of my Microsoft mouse the default values were `1 1 1` which are way too sensitive.

`10 10 10` are right for me.

I didn't take the time to see what each number actually means

Comment: the number immediately following `set-prop` is the device ID (I believe.) You can check this with xinput list. You'll see your device IDs listed in order. 

Get the available properties with `xinput list-props [id]`

Comment: Here's what the Evdev params mean: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442666

Answer (score 0):

For those, who prefer to fix it `Linux Desktop Way`.

Wrote exhaustive instruction on how to add `Scroll Ratio` through libinput sources:

https://github.com/up-to-you/linux_notes/blob/master/mouse/scroll_speed.md

For those, who hates `github` (`gitlab` funs?), duplicated here (works for any mouse):

find libinput files

```
sudo updatedb
ll $(locate -A libinput.so)
```

most likely Canonical delivers their libinput libs with snaps

```
sudo snap list
sudo snap remove gnome-3-28-1804
```

check, that libinput lefts only in system folder, like :
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput.so`
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput.so.10`
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput.so.10.13.0`

```
ll $(locate -A libinput.so)
```

clone libinput source

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput
cd libinput
```

modify `src/evdev.c`. Find `evdev_read_wheel_click_props` function and init `angles.y = 361`;

```
static inline struct wheel_angle
evdev_read_wheel_click_props(struct evdev_device *device)
{
    struct wheel_angle angles;
    const char *wheel_count = "MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_COUNT";
    const char *wheel_angle = "MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE";
    const char *hwheel_count = "MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_COUNT_HORIZONTAL";
    const char *hwheel_angle = "MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE_HORIZONTAL";

    /* CLICK_COUNT overrides CLICK_ANGLE */
    if (evdev_read_wheel_click_count_prop(device, wheel_count, &angles.y) ||
        evdev_read_wheel_click_prop(device, wheel_angle, &angles.y)) {
        evdev_log_debug(device,
                "wheel: vert click angle: %.2f\n", angles.y);
    }
    if (evdev_read_wheel_click_count_prop(device, hwheel_count, &angles.x) ||
        evdev_read_wheel_click_prop(device, hwheel_angle, &angles.x)) {
        evdev_log_debug(device,
                "wheel: horizontal click angle: %.2f\n", angles.y);
    } else {
        angles.x = angles.y;
    }
    // since, src/util-prop-parsers.c : abs(angle) > 360
    angles.y = 361;

    return angles;
}
```

modify `src/libinput.c`. Find `libinput_event_pointer_get_axis_value_discrete` function and apply scroll ratio as you wish:

```
LIBINPUT_EXPORT double
libinput_event_pointer_get_axis_value_discrete(struct libinput_event_pointer *event,
                           enum libinput_pointer_axis axis)
{
    struct libinput *libinput = event->base.device->seat->libinput;
    double value = 0;

    require_event_type(libinput_event_get_context(&event->base),
               event->base.type,
               0.0,
               LIBINPUT_EVENT_POINTER_AXIS);

    if (!libinput_event_pointer_has_axis(event, axis)) {
        log_bug_client(libinput, "value requested for unset axis\n");
    } else {
        switch (axis) {
        case LIBINPUT_POINTER_AXIS_SCROLL_HORIZONTAL:
      // x5 ratio for horizontal scrolling
            value = event->discrete.x * 5;
            break;
        case LIBINPUT_POINTER_AXIS_SCROLL_VERTICAL:
      // x5 ratio for vertical scrolling
            value = event->discrete.y * 5;
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Prepare build directory (dependencies installation required):

```
meson --prefix=/usr builddir/ -Ddocumentation=false
```

Compile and install:

```
ninja -C builddir/ && sudo ninja -C builddir/ install
```

Verify location:

```
sudo updatedb
ll $(locate -A libinput.so)
```

Logout / Login , use.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I have made good experience with `mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.enabled` set to `true`. This keeps the `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount` intact, which is good for precision. You can additionally set the scroll factor higher: `mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.vertical.factor` (default. 200).

### Firefox 80 / `about:config`

1. Set `mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.enabled` to `true`
2. (optionally) Increase `mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.vertical.factor` (default. 200)

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to increase the mouse scroll wheel acceleration, and not just the absolute speed. This is a feature in MacOSX but not builtin for Xorg (also Wayland) yet.

I implemented such a feature in user space [here (mouse-scroll-wheel-acceleration-userspace)](https://github.com/albertz/mouse-scroll-wheel-acceleration-userspace).
This will increase the scroll speed, or accelerate the scroll speed.
You would just run this in the background, with your preferred options.
The code is quite simple Python code, and should be easy to modify as well.