# How can I adjust the scroll sensitivity down?

Tags: mouse-scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increasing scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/increasing-scroll-speed)

I have a wireless mouse, and the scroll sensitivity - especially in firefox - is set way too high.

Is there a simple way to decrease it?  Right now, the slightest touch on the wheel jumps to the bottom of the page.  It's a Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 5000 if that makes a difference.  (I also have a wireless logitech mouse attached to the same system, and the scroll speed is fine - if it wasn't for a bad button, I'd be happy to keep it.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm only aware of a way to fix this within Firefox itself, not Ubuntu-wide.

In your address bar, type `about:config` and then change `mousewheel.withnokey.sysnumlines` to false and `mousewheel.withnokey.numlines` to a number smaller than the default of 6.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that Ubuntu's Mouse Preferences has a way to change the scroll wheel's behavior. You can find Mouse Preferences by hitting the Super key (or Windows key) and typing Mouse.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to get there in Unity. But If you log in With `Ubuntu classic` from the log in screen. Then go to  `System > Prefences > Mouse Settings`  there you can slow it down or speed it up

Comment: This did not work for me, I was still not able to access the scroll-wheel properties in classic, just the mouse movement speed which is different.