# Decrease mouse scroll amount

Tags: touchpad, mouse-scroll

How can I decrease (or generally change) the mouse wheel scroll amount in Ubuntu? I didn't mean the speed of scroll, and the thing I want is just the amount. for example, when reading a document, I want to scroll one line instead of three lines (with scrolling a little).

Comment: Is this question a duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/52250/how-can-i-adjust-the-scroll-sensitivity-down

Comment: similiar but not duplicate. and ,with no answers suitable for me.

Comment: 12.04 has smooth scrolling so for instance you can scroll in gedit 1 line at a time.

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtk/+bug/124440

Comment: No, no, that's not a bug, I just want it to be a little bit different. If 12.04 has smooth scrolling, that will be OK.

Comment: If you just want smooth scrolling, Firefox has it already, so you can enable it at least for that application.

Comment: I believe this is efectively a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/increasing-scroll-speed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/increasing-scroll-speed) This could also be VTC as not reproducible as this refers to Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Although the duplicate candidate states "increasing scroll speed" it effectively means "changing scroll speed" which is +/- in the answers.