# How can I configure the mouse scrollwheel sensitivity?

Tags: gnome, configuration, mouse, mouse-scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increasing scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/increasing-scroll-speed)

Is there anyway to increase the speed of the wheel scrolling of my mouse in Ubuntu? I use extended files (PDFs, web pages etc) and I need to quickly look through them.

I read somewhere that Kubuntu has this option in preference panel mouse but Ubuntu doesn't so I'm stuck.