# How to set the scroll speed of apple magic mouse?

Tags: apple, magic-mouse

How to set the scroll speed of apple magic mouse?

I only found the moving speed.

Comment: Currently there is no way to do it GUI-way system wide. See this for some workarounds: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/ In web browsers, it can be set separately (Firefox, Chromium/Chrome).

Answer (score 20):

At the moment only way is setup it directly in hid_magicmouse driver.

For testing run:

```
sudo rmmod hid_magicmouse
# scroll-speed value from 0 (slow) to 63 (fast):
sudo modprobe hid_magicmouse scroll-speed=45 scroll-acceleration=1
```

For permanent settings put to the /etc/modprobe.d/magicmouse.conf this:

```
options hid_magicmouse scroll-speed=45 scroll-acceleration=1
```

Comment: any other elegant way to change it instead of using command?

Comment: There's nothing more elegant as the command line :-)

Comment: @王子1986 Of cause there is. create a text file at /etc/modprobe.d/hid_magicmouse.conf with following lines: `options hid_magicmouse scroll_speed=50
options hid_magicmouse scroll_acceleration=1`, the module will be loaded with specified options.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04. The mouse is detected and the scroll is working. But the permanent setting is not working. Is there any other elegant way to make the settings permanent?

Answer (score 3):

You can also write to the parameters via the /sys kernel interface:

```
$ ls /sys/module/hid_magicmouse/parameters/
emulate_3button  emulate_scroll_wheel  report_undeciphered  scroll_acceleration  scroll_speed
$ cat /sys/module/hid_magicmouse/parameters/scroll_speed
45
$ echo N | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_magicmouse/parameters/scroll_acceleration 
N
```

You can ogle the source here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/hid-magicmouse.c