# Ubuntu 12.04 Magic Mouse connected and paired but not working

Tags: 12.04, kernel, bluetooth, input-devices, magic-mouse

I have a problem with Magic Mouse. It was working for a time, but after I updated the system it won't work. It connects fine, pairs, the green light on the mouse lights up, and Blueman says it's connected and paired, but when I click or move the mouse nothing happens. The mouse is working fine on another PC.

`Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsmod | grep magic` returns nothing. `sudo lsinput | grep magic` returns nothing, and before magic mouse was listed there in both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found what was the problem

i wanted to change scrool speed like

it was explainde  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261791/how-to-set-the-scroll-speed-of-apple-magic-mouse)

i put hid-magicmouse  instead of hid_  and put a value of 100 for scrooll speed and found reponse in dmesg

> [ 1759.669463] hid_magicmouse: `100' invalid for parameter`scroll-speed'

Comment: Yep. 59 is a maximum, for nor real reason.