# How am I expected to scroll fine distances if I can't change the scroll distance or middle-click and drag to scroll?

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

I can't find anything for this, I use a dell USB mouse, no special buttons or hardware, I regularly need to be able to scroll by couple-pixel distances, mostly in chrome, but for my sanity the ability to do it in everything else would be extremely helpful, according to other questions I found, I can't just change the number of scroll lines and the middle-click scroll is apparently taken up by xclipboard or something,

What do I do? I've run out of ideas, I just came from windows, where this was solved by autoscroll on middle-click and drag, and the ability of my laptop in particular to scroll by 1 pixel in any direction by using the numberpad arrows system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Increase Mouse-key acceleration?

Firstly open a terminal window and type the following to install the xkbset package:

```
sudo apt-get install xkbset
```

A simple one line command can then be used to configure the acceleration:

```
xkbset ma [delay] [interval] [time to max] [max speed] [curve]
```

For those new to command-line interfaces, the brackets imply that they need to be replaced by a numerical value, tailored to suite a particular use. I have recently used the following for my configuration:

```
xkbset ma 60 10 10 20 10
```

Comment: No, I think he's asking to be able to middle click and drag to scroll in a certain direction - something that happens by default in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan) for chrome, it should do what you want via ctrl+leftclick.

Comment: That's perfect for chrome, but is there nothing I can do for all the other software?

Comment: @Face I'm still looking because this is something I miss too.

Comment: @Face I don't think there is a solution, unfortunately... I'm still going to keep looking though.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb) gives you fine-grained control over how your mouse wheel and keyboard perform scrolling in **Google Chrome** and the Chromium browser.  Unfortunately setting a low step size will not provide a very fast maximum speed, so you may need to sacrifice your keyboard to perform small scrolls, and keep your mouse for general scrolling.

The app suggested by Tim is likely to be more useful.

Another option is this [Auto Scroll Keys](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/7658-auto-scroll-keys) userscript (which I have worked on but did not initially create).  But that's not trivial to install if you don't already have TamperMonkey.

Some discussion about adjusting **Firefox** scroll speed [can be found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/increasing-scroll-speed/704252).  You should be able to reduce the speed using the same techniques.

[**Gnome-wide** settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/increasing-scroll-speed/704252#27276) are also discussed on that page, but unfortunately the feature doesn't appear to be available just yet (2015).